# How do I solve $x'+x = t^2 *x^4$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve $x'+x = t^2 *x^4$?
So far I have:
$x = 0$ is one answer, so I can divide by $x^4$ and substitute $y = z^{(-3)}$, and that's where I'm stuck with no idea on how to continue.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: this is a Bernoulli equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{x'}{x^4} + \frac{1}{x^3} = t^2$$

With $z = 1/x^3$, then $\displaystyle z' = -3\frac{x'}{x^4}$.

Substitute back into the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing your equation by $-\frac13 x^4$ we get $-\frac{3x'}{x^4}-\frac{3}{x^3}=-3t^2$ and doing your substitution we have $y'-3y=-3t^2$. This is standard; Multiply both sides by $e^{-3t}$. This should be enough of a hint.